# What do I do about my Ether since the 2019 Constantinople upgrade has been postponed?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, constantinople

With the last minute postponement of the 2019 Constantinople upgrade. What do I do about my stored Ether? And what software do I need to upgrade to if I am running Geth or Parity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything about your ether - if you ran a parity or geth node, you need to be on a version that either didn't support the fork in the first place, or reverted the fork - other than that, your node will handle reorganization/syncing to the correct fork.

More information, including specific version numbers, here: https://www.parity.io/security-alert-ethereum-constantinople-postponement/